# Как создать страницу со случайным названием и перейти на нее после выполненный условий?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php5

Это все - что пока есть:

```
<?php
$to = rand() . "\n";
?>
```

```
    <script>
    window.location.href = "index.html";
    </script>
```

Comment: Вам нужны разные файлы? Или разные титлы? (Вам нужны разные физически файлы, или просто страницы у который будет рандомный title и контент)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы создать файл нужно использовать методы PHP связанные с файлами. Вы можете создать опеределённый шаблон который будете загружать в сам файл:

```
<?php
$templateFile = fopen("template.html", "r+");
$template = fread($templateFile, filesize("template.html"));

$random = rand();
$file = fopen("$random.php", "w");
fwrite($file, $template);

header("Location: $random.php");
```

В template.html мы занесли стандартную разметку html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, 
    maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>FILE</title>
</head>
 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Затем мы просто получаем разметку с шаблона, генерируем число, записываем его в переменную, далее используем эту переменную как назвние файла, создаём его.

В файл записываем полученную разметку, как шаблон. Далее просто переходим на неё.

Comment: Вы какой то дикий бред напили, товарищь.

Comment: Почему же бред? В template.html записать стандартную разметку html, и вот полностью рабочий способ, который был нужен автору вопроса, в очень короткой форме.

Comment: А для чего это делать, когда вопросы адреса страницы решаются средствами HTTP сервера?

Comment: **Как создать страницу со случайным названием и перейти на нее после выполненный условий?** Таким был вопрос. Я дал ответ.